# repeat header and footer when content overflow on firstpage

Tags: html, css, printing

I know that my question might be duplicate to other questions I tried other solution but it failed to work for me. In my case i used `header` to use as static header for printing and used `div` as my footer and as for my content i use table to display the data..

so my problem now is when I tried printing the page if the content from the table overflows it goes to 2nd page. what I wanted to make is when my table overflows on the 1st page it should go to the 2nd page and the header and footer will also be seen in the 2nd page and so on..

**HEADER**

```
  <header>  
        <center><h3><b>Miguel Enrique</b></h3>                  
        <p><i>Diplomat<br>Fellow</i><br>Orthopaedic Surgeon</p>         
        </center>
    </header>
<div class="row uniform half collapse-at-2">
  <div class="12u">                                     
    <center><h4><b>---data----</b></h4></center>
    <h4><p>------DATA--------------<br>Tel. 77 19 349 | 65 90 097
    <br>Mon<b>&middot;</b>Wed<b>&middot;</b>Fri  |  3:00pm - 5:00pm
    <br>Tues<b>&middot;</b>Thurs<b>&middot;</b>Sat  |  11:00am - 2:00pm  | 
    <br>  (All by appointment)</p></h5>
  </div>
  <div class="6u">
    <div class="row uniform half">
        <div class="12u">
        <center><h4><b>--DATA---</b></h4></center>                                                      
        <h5><p>  ------DATA-------
        <br>Tel. No. : (632) 789 - 7700 loc. 7330
        <br>Mon-Thurs: 11am - 4pm  |  (by Appointment)</p><h5>
        </div>                              
    </div>
  </div>
<div
```

**BODY**

```
<table class="print">
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"><b>No.</b></th>
            <th scope="col"><b>Prescriptions</b></th>
        </tr>
   </thead>
    <tbody>                                         
        <?php foreach($new_array2 as  $value) { $inc = @$inc + 1;?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $inc; $prescription_array=explode('/',$value);?>
            </td>
            <td><?php foreach($prescription_array as $value2) 
              { echo "<h5>".$value2."</h5>";
            } ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <?php }?>
   </tbody>                                                                 
</table>
```

**FOOTER**

```
<div class="row uniform half collapse-at-2">
    <div class="12u">                       
        <div class="row uniform half">
           <font size="5"><b>Name</b></font><br>
            License No. : 1<br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

is there any way to solve this?? when printing if the content overflows on the 1st page it will go to 2nd page and the header and footer will be displayed on the 2nd page ?.
[image]

First image is about what happens when i try to print. what i want to achieve is on the second picture below. Is it possible using google chrome?.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

header

```
<header>  
    <center><h3><b>Miguel Enrique</b></h3>                  
    <p><i>Diplomat<br>Fellow</i><br/>Orthopaedic Surgeon</p>         
    </center>
</header>
<div class="row uniform half collapse-at-2">
  <div class="12u">                                     
    <center><h4><b>---data----</b></h4></center>
    <h4><p>------DATA--------------<br/>
        Tel. 77 19 349 | 65 90 097<br/>
        Mon<b>&middot;</b>Wed<b>&middot;</b>Fri  |  3:00pm - 5:00pm<br/>
        Tues<b>&middot;</b>Thurs<b>&middot;</b>Sat  |  11:00am - 2:00pm  |<br/> 
        (All by appointment)</p>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="6u">
    <div class="row uniform half">
        <div class="12u">
            <center><h4><b>--DATA---</b></h4></center>                                                      
            <h5><p>  ------DATA-------<br/>
            Tel. No. : (632) 789 - 7700 loc. 7330<br/>
            Mon-Thurs: 11am - 4pm  |  (by Appointment)</p></h5>
        </div>                              
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

body

```
<table class="print">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"><b>No.</b></th>
            <th scope="col"><b>Prescriptions</b></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                                         
        <?php 
        foreach($new_array2 as  $value) 
            { 
                $inc = @$inc + 1;
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php 
                    echo $inc; 
                    $prescription_array=explode('/',$value);
                ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php 
                    foreach($prescription_array as $value2) 
                        { 
                            echo "<h5>".$value2."</h5>";
                        } 
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            }
        ?>
   </tbody>                                                                 
</table>
```

footer

```
<div class="row uniform half collapse-at-2">
    <div class="12u">                       
        <div class="row uniform half">
           <font size="5"><b>Name</b></font><br/>
            License No. : 1<br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```